# How to get index from an arrayList based on their weightage in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of transactions for a database in java. Each query has some weight associated with it. I want to execute that transaction that many number of times.

For eg putting 1 transaction in JSON format:-

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "name": "NewOrder",
    "weight": 45,
    "queries": [
      {
        "query": "select * from account where id > ? and balance > ?",
        "bindParams": [
          {
            "utilityFunction": {
              "name": "randomString",
              "params": [
                {
                  "minLen": 8,
                  "maxLen": 16
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "utilityFunction": {
              "name": "randomInteger",
              "params": [
                {
                  "minValue": 100000,
                  "maxLen": 100000
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

I have similar transactions with weights which add upto 100.
I now want to get the id of this transaction from the arraylist of transactions based on its weight.

For eg(transaction names and their weight):-

new order :-45(weight)

stockpurchase:- 30(weight)

newitems :- 15(weight)

deliveryitems :- 10 (weight)

I created an arrayList of integers which stores the sum till that index of transaction :-

[45,75,90,100]

Now I am thinking on invoking a random number[1-100] and get the index that lies closest to it to get the index from the arrayList of transactions.
Is this implementation correct or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You have a list of _transaction_. Each _transaction_ has a _name_ and a _weight_. Now you want to generate a random _weight_ value and locate the _transaction_ whose _weight_ is closest to the randomly generated _weight_ and you are asking how to implement that. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: @Abra yes correct.

Comment: So just iterate through the list of _transaction_ and for each _transaction_ subtract its _weight_ from the random _weight_. You want the _transaction_ where the absolute difference in weights is closest to zero. Do you want me to show you the code for achieving what I just described?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the JSON for the other transactions, i.e. `stockpurchase`, `newitems` and `deliveryitems` so that I can create a list of _transaction_ which I can then iterate through and search, as I described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert your schema to POJO. like this

```
 package com.example;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.annotation.Generated;
    
    public class BindParam {
    
    private UtilityFunction utilityFunction;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    public UtilityFunction getUtilityFunction() {
    return utilityFunction;
    }
    
    public void setUtilityFunction(UtilityFunction utilityFunction) {
    this.utilityFunction = utilityFunction;
    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
    }
    
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
    
    }
   
    
    package com.example;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.annotation.Generated;
    
   
    public class Param {
    
    private Integer minLen;
    private Integer maxLen;
    private Integer minValue;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    public Integer getMinLen() {
    return minLen;
    }
    
    public void setMinLen(Integer minLen) {
    this.minLen = minLen;
    }
    
    public Integer getMaxLen() {
    return maxLen;
    }
    
    public void setMaxLen(Integer maxLen) {
    this.maxLen = maxLen;
    }
    
    public Integer getMinValue() {
    return minValue;
    }
    
    public void setMinValue(Integer minValue) {
    this.minValue = minValue;
    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
    }
    
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
    
    }
   
    
    package com.example;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.annotation.Generated;
    
   
    public class Query {
    
    private String query;
    private List<BindParam> bindParams = null;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    public String getQuery() {
    return query;
    }
    
    public void setQuery(String query) {
    this.query = query;
    }
    
    public List<BindParam> getBindParams() {
    return bindParams;
    }
    
    public void setBindParams(List<BindParam> bindParams) {
    this.bindParams = bindParams;
    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
    }
    
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
    
    }
   
    
    package com.example;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.annotation.Generated;
    
    @Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
    public class Transaction {
    
    private String name;
    private Integer weight;
    private List<Query> queries = null;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Integer getWeight() {
    return weight;
    }
    
    public void setWeight(Integer weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
    }
    
    public List<Query> getQueries() {
    return queries;
    }
    
    public void setQueries(List<Query> queries) {
    this.queries = queries;
    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
    }
    
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
    
    }

    
    package com.example;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.annotation.Generated;
    
    @Generated("jsonschema2pojo")
    public class UtilityFunction {
    
    private String name;
    private List<Param> params = null;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }
    
    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
    
    public List<Param> getParams() {
    return params;
    }
    
    public void setParams(List<Param> params) {
    this.params = params;
    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
    }
    
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
    
    }
    
    package com.example;
    
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.annotation.Generated;
    
    
    public class WrapperClass {
    
    private Transaction transaction;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    
    public Transaction getTransaction() {
    return transaction;
    }
    
    public void setTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
    this.transaction = transaction;
    }
    
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
    }
    
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }
    
    }
 public class Main() {
    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        //assume that you collect data from getValue()
        List<WrapperClass> wrappers = getValue();
        for(WrapperClass wrapper : wrappers) {
            Transaction transaction = wrapper.getTransaction();
             int weight = transaction.getWeight();

}
         
    }
}
```

you can use [JSONSchema2POJO](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate model from json.